# Modeling a curve edge of a plane

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm new to blender and trying to model the blade of my helicopter and can't figure out how to make an edge curved (for the red tip and selected edge). The object is a plane, with one loop cut. I attempted making a bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>, but nothing happens (A dotted line appears attached to the cursor, moving does nothing, left-clicking does nothing).  also I cant add a *curve* modifier, just says its disabled. What is the correct way to model this? [image: blade]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The curve modifier is not aimed for this. And Bevel tool doesn't work like this, either. The best way to control planar curvature is by using curves, which may not well benefit topology, however.

I recommend to use Subsurf modifier + edge creases. Add some loop cuts first, then with a few tweaks on the vertex position (<kbd>G</kbd>) and adjust crease weight (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) on some edges, you can make whatever you want with nice topology. I'm sure you also want to bend it later, so topology is important to consider in advance.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I would like to add (for my own future reference, and others) edge creases lessens the rounding effect caused when applying the subsurface modifier [link](http://archive.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-234/weighted-creases-for-subsurfs/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can try creating your object as a [**curve**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves).
[image]

Make it a 2d curve, fill it and give it some bevel.

[image]

[image]

You might choose at this point to convert your curve into a mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or keep working with your object as a curve...

Comment: Alt C is going to give you the worst topology imaginable. Don't use this.

Comment: Nice! I made one (using the bezier curve) and it looks beautiful! I made it solid by selecting the start and end vertex and pressing the f key, but (Alt C) is just undoing the connecting edge(what the f key did) rather than converting it to a mesh. what am i doing wrong? @GiantCowFilms thanks for the tip, but still curious :D

Comment: @GiantCowFilms There are cases where topology is unimportant, and converting to a mesh isn't needed..