# tapering a custom object

Tags: extrude

I took an flat image of a fish fin and used image J to convert it to a series of points which I connected. I extruded it from 2D image to 3D in inventor, and converted that ipt file to an stl file. I uploaded this into blender and want to taper the edges of the fin so that it is not a completely flat object. [image]

I am trying to resemble a real fish fin in life which is thicker at the base and then thins out as you reach the tip. I have no experience with blender and limited modelling experience. Is there a way to taper the edges on an imported stl object? All the videos I saw on youtube used circular objects and were able to use the taper tool but my object is not cylindrical. The option to taper does not show up for me.

Another way is to just upload the 2D points into blender and perform the extrusion in blender instead of importing an extruded fin. I have the points in an excel sheet but I would have to convert them into a python array. Which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I suggest you start over... This would be easy with a curve: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15935/modeling-a-curve-edge-of-a-plane/15937#15937 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63287/curves-in-plain-edges/63298#63298

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61301/extruding-inwards-along-edges/61319#61319

Comment: Could you briefly explain what you mean by start over, without using specialized language? Should I import the points via python array (I don't know how to switch xlsx into python array) and then connect the points as a curve? The post referring to the blade tapers it the wrong way for me. I want to like vary the width of the fin as it goes from base to tip, not a constant taper between two uneven faces of the fin (if that makes sense).